# vue-router doesn't render components when one of them has multiple components

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

So I have this Home page and a navbar with: `Home | About | Services`
The problem is when I try to switch between `Home` and `About`, only the components of Home are shown
Here is my `HomeComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header-component :logo="logo" />
    <router-view />
    <FooterComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the Header component where the router links are

```
 <nav>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'Body' }" class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900"
          >Home</router-link
        >
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'About' }" class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900"
          >About</router-link
        >
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'Services' }" class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900"
          >Services</router-link
        >
</nav>
```

this is the `router.js`

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                name: "Body",
                component: HomeContent,
            },
            {
                path: "about",
                name: "About",
                component: About,
            },
            {
                path: "services",
                name: "Services",
                component: Services,
            },
        ],
    }, ]
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes, 
});

export default router;
```

This is the HomeContent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HeroComponent :heroImg="heroImg" />
    <FeatureComponent />
    <TestimonialsComponent />
    <ContactComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the About component

```
<template>
  <h1>About</h1>
</template>
```

So when I first launched my site, the `HomeContent` renders normally, but when I go to `About`, nothing changes, but when I refresh the page, then the `About component` renders
then if I click on `Home` the `HomeContent` renders and the problems happen again

Comment: Is your path properly created when clicking on the About / Home ?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari yes the paths are created properly, when i click on Home: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and when I click on About: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about

Comment: add key to HomeComponent.vue:
<router-view :key="$route.path" />